# lftp error: port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss

Tags: ssh, sftp, ubuntu-18.04, openssh, lftp

How do I fix this error, `no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss` when doing lftp on a vm with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

I've tried adding

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

to my `~/.ssh/config` file, but I am still seeing the error.  I'm trying to avoid editing my `/etc/ssh/config` file because I can't afford to restart my ssh server.  Is there an option I can pass in with lftp at run time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a hack, where I leverage use some ssh options within the lftp command.

```
lftp -p 22 -u <username>,<password> sftp://<domain> -e 'set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss"'
```

Answer (score 9):

Fixed by adding PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes to my .ssh/config

```
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Worked for me. I think it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69657512/11774808.

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` and `HostKeyAlgorithms` to `+ssh-rsa` worked

```bash
lftp \
    -p 22 \
    -u "${USR}","${PW}" "sftp://${URL}" \
    -e "set sftp:connect-program 'ssh -a -x -o PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa'; mirror --continue --parallel=10 ${REMOTE_FOLDER} ${OUTPUT_FOLDER}; exit"
```