# Git Bash - ssh connection issue

Tags: git, windows-10, gerrit

**Environment:**

```
OS: Windows-10
Git Bash Version: 2.33.1
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
$ which ssh
 /usr/bin/ssh
```

**SSH connection to Gerrit Error:-**

```
$ ssh -p 29418 user@gerrit.example.com

Unable to negotiate with gerrit.example.com port 29418: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

In `Git-2.32.0` ssh connection to gerrit works. Is there any restriction enabled in latest git version?

Comment: It looks like the latest version of git is deprecating insecure algorithms and your Gerrit instance is unable to connect with more modern options

Comment: This is not a problem with git. You have better chances to find a solution when you search for "ssh".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Git For Windows 2.33.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.1.windows.1) comes with [OpenSSH 8.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) which disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm by default.

> For most users, this change should be invisible and there is
> no need to replace ssh-rsa keys.
> OpenSSH has supported RFC8332
> RSA/SHA-256/512 signatures since release 7.2 and existing ssh-rsa keys
> will automatically use the stronger algorithm where possible.
>
> Incompatibility is more likely when connecting to older SSH
> implementations that have not been upgraded or have not closely tracked
> improvements in the SSH protocol.
>
> For these cases, it may be necessary
> to selectively re-enable RSA/SHA1 to allow connection and/or user
> authentication via the HostkeyAlgorithms and PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
> options.
> For example, the following stanza in ~/.ssh/config will enable
> RSA/SHA1 for host and user authentication for a single destination host:
>
> ```
> Host old-host
>    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
>    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
> ```

Note: [Git for Windows 2.34.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.0.windows.1) does not bring any new element/evolution on the SSH front.

---

[Stefan Prodan](https://twitter.com/stefanprodan) (DX @weaveworks, creator of http://flagger.app and maintainer of http://fluxcd.io) mentions in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/stefanprodan/status/1460711058629353473):

> GitHub has changed its host keys
>
> If you're using @fluxcd please see here how to update the known hosts keys on your Kubernetes clusters.

Stefan refers to [`fluxcd/flux2` discussion 2097](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2/discussions/2097):

> GitHub has [changed its SSH host keys from RSA to ECDSA](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/)!
>
> To fix the key mismatch error, you have two options:
>
> 1. Update the `known_hosts` in the flux-system secret with the ecdsa-sha2-nistp25 value:
>
> `github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=`
>
> 2. Or rotate the SSH keys with flux boostrap like so:
>
> - delete the deploy key secret from your cluster `kubectl -n flux-system delete secret flux-system`
> - rerun `flux bootstrap github` with the same arguments as before
>
> Flux will generate the secret with ecdsa-sha2 SSH key and Host key
>
> More details on [`fluxcd/source-controller`#490](https://github.com/fluxcd/source-controller/issues/490)

---

Note: [since Jan. 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/), the GitHub SSH Host key are available through a metadata endpoint [`api.github.com/meta`](https://api.github.com/meta).
That includes the `github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` value.

Comment: `~/.ssh/config` method also doesn't work. Still same error persisting. Even in `Git Windows - 2.34.0` version also same issue.

Comment: Just for testing, would an older version of Git work better? (2.30 for instance?)

Comment: Yes until this `Git Client version for Windows -2.32.0` it is working fine.

Comment: @user4948798 Is it possible that it is using the wrong SSH? (Windows instead of Git packaged SSH: https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/367)

Comment: @user4948798 I believe I have found a possible solution: see my edited answer and update your client `~/.ssh/known_hosts` as detailed in said answer.

Comment: Additionally added `Port 29418` in the `~/.ssh/config` it is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user4948798 Perfect, well done!

Comment: @VonC How did you get the value of ecdsa-sha2-nistp256?

Comment: @Raulp https://github.blog/changelog/githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/ and https://api.github.com/meta

Answer (score 10):

Facing the same problem. The solution is to add the following to ~/.ssh/config

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa    
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Cannot have Host as in the accepted answer. Must be exactly as above. I guess each server may be configured in different ways and individual may have to experiment.

Comment: For git for Windows this lives in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`

Comment: I've confirmed this works on Git 2.39.1.windows.1. Both lines must be added to the top of .ssh/config as opposed to a host configuration.

Comment: This is not a good (long-term) solution since it weakens encryption. ["It is now possible to perform chosen-prefix attacks against the SHA-1 hash algorithm for less than USD$50K."](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2). The correct solution is to switch to a different signature algorithm.

Comment: Works for me in my WSL2.

Answer (score 1):

This thread was recommended to me as I was facing the same issue but was not using gerrit.

I tried using the answered solution but it didn't work for me.

So for anyone in the same situation, adding just the below line in `~/.ssh/config` did resolve the issue for me.

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: This is not a good (long-term) solution since it weakens encryption. See my comment on toddwz's answer.