# how to get http password in gerrit rest api

Tags: gerrit

I want to look up some review comments on Gerrit via the REST API.
I tried a few methods, including Gerrit's official documentation, and nothing changed the fact that I was an anonymous user. The authentication configuration in the `gerrit.config` is as follow:

```ini
[auth]
    type = LDAP
    gitBasicAuthPolicy = LDAP
```

I'm calling rest api by curl

```console
$ curl --digest --user LDAP_user:LDAP_password \
      https://gerrit.example.com/a/path/to/api
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP_PASSWORD maybe the answer which can be found in account settings.

And then

```
curl -u USR_NAME:HTTP_PASSWORD https://gerrit.XX.com/a/path/to/api
```

Answer (score 1):

Digest authentication was removed from Gerrit in release 2.14. Remove the "--digest" parameter and the "curl" command will work.

More info in Gerrit 2.14 release notes [here](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/2.14.html#http-digest-authentication-removed).

Comment: I have removed digest parameter but it doesn't work. My gerrit version is:3.1.7

Comment: What's the error? Can you log in UI with the same user/password?

Comment: Yes I can login in UI with the same user/password. But it does'nt work in rest api. I don't know if it has anything to do with ldap configuration

Comment: I use "HTTP_LDAP" instead of "LDAP" in the "gitBasicAuthPolicy" configuration, but I think this isn't an issue. You need to show what is the EXACT command you're running and what is the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

What's your Gerrit version?
2.14 and newer require basic auth, as already mentioned by Marcelo (maybe you have to explicitly give `--basic` ).
2.13 and older use digest; you will also be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69657512/3301051) if you are using versions that old.